# hyper-v error manage VM

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v

I have a problem in the management of the machines in Hyper-V, when I try to open the console I get the following error:

> an error occurred while attempting to launch the Virtual Machine
>   Connection application for the selected virtualmachine

however when I click on the settings I get this other:

> Cannot access the settings for the selected virtual machine. the
>   computer "localhost" failed to perform the requested operation
>   I try to describe the scenario:

all the machines in question belong to a domain; I have a server (servergui) with windows server 2008 enterprise SP2, on which a VM is started (vmsrvgui1) with installed windows2003, trying to open the console in hyper-v manager, I get the above error, the VM vmsrvgui1 is run and I can access it in remote desktop.

Then I have another machine (ServerCore) with installed windows server 2008 enterprise SP1 only core installation with hyper-v, on which there are some virtual machine(4 in run and other 4 in stop), of which even the domain controller.

By servergui add ServerCore by 'hyper-v manager', I get the list of machines available but trying to execute any operation I get the same errors above.

sometimes I get the error in hyper-v manager "RPC server unavaiable, unable to establish communication between servercore and servergui on ServerCore", but removing the server and add again i can see the lists of Vm.

any idea? thanks for now and sorry for my english ;)

Comment: In the best practice you should always have a physical DC, as if you have only one in hyper-v, I suspect a communication error to your DC as you got rpc error and strange error

Comment: I know that's not a good idea to have the dc virtualized, but unfortunately this is a farm that I inherited. the thing that seems strange is that I can not handle the VM hosted locally.I tried to follow this guide http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2008/03/28/part-1-hyper-v-remote-management-you-do-not-have-the-requested-permission-to-complete-this-task-contact-the-administrator-of-the-authorization-policy-for-the-computer-computername.aspx but did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I solved by changing the sid of the owner from the xml file of VMs